# Flask(Python) Broken Pipe Error

Tags: python, sockets, flask, pipe

I am running a Flask framework on a Apache Web Server, but I got the following errors now and then, can somebody help me with this? When I got this error, my web server just doesn't respond to any requests.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 284, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 310, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 641, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 694, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Comment: Are you actually running a server, or are you using the development server?

Comment: Thank you Blender. I am running it on an Apache Server.

Comment: How? FastCGI? [WSGI](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/)?

Comment: I am not sure, but I just used the built in Apache server from Mac. I guess it is WSGI, isn't it?

Comment: How did you set it up?

Comment: Thank you for asking. I set it up according to this post: http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/02/start-apache-web-server-mac-os-x/

Comment: You'll have to setup [Apache to work with mod_wsgi](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/). You can also use [Gunicorn](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#gunicorn), which is much faster and is easier to setup.

Comment: Thank you for your help Blender, this is really helpful. I will lood into it.

Comment: `Broken pipe` is common in development server, maybe you should try `Gunicorn` + `Nginx` in production environment.